# How to build Che Theia image with my own changes?

Tags: eclipse-che, theia

I have cloned Theia and made some changes and I would like to provide a patch to a specific version of Theia, or I would like to test a specific branch in Theia repo or I have written a Theia extension or plugin and want to have theses one by default included in che-theia, etc ... How could I rebuild the che-theia image to use it in Che ?

Answer (score 1):

The sources of eclipse/che-theia is located [here](https://github.com/eclipse/che/tree/master/dockerfiles/theia).
After the changes are made, you need to rebuild the image with the following command:
using build script:

`$ ./build.sh --build-args:GITHUB_TOKEN=$GITHUB_TOKEN,THEIA_VERSION=0.3.13 --tag:0.3.13-nightly`

or using docker:

`$ docker build -t eclipse/che-theia:0.3.13-nightly --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN={your token} --build-arg THEIA_VERSION=0.3.13 .`

Integration tests are launched by default during the build. It is possible to skip with the option `--skip-tests`

`./build.sh --skip-tests`